How can I dynamically change the items in my map without creating a new key?
I have the following sandbox
import "./styles.css";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  interface filter {
    company: boolean;
    gender: boolean;
  }
  const [people, setPeople] = useState<filter>({
    company: false,
    gender: false,
  });

    useEffect(() => {
    console.log(people);
  }, [people]);


  const toggleMenu = (menuItem: keyof typeof people) => {
    setPeople({ ...people, menuItem: !people[menuItem] });
  };


  return (
    <div className="App">
                    <button
                className="flex flex-row justify-center w-full"
                onClick={() => toggleMenu("company")}
              >
Click me 
</button>
    </div>
  );
}

The toggleMenu function doesn't seem to work correctly. The idea is to pass an arbitrary key (e.g. "company") and have it toggle the value. Instead, I get the following output:
{company: false, gender: false, menuItem: true}
WHereas I want:
{company: true, gender: false}
I tried the code above but didn't expect to see a new key created in my map...just need to update the existing key.

The problem is you are adding a new key of menuItem to your people object. You need to add brackets around the key instead:
const toggleMenu = (menuItem: keyof typeof people) => {
  setPeople({ ...people, [menuItem]: !people[menuItem]
  });
};

I've refactored your code into a more readable version with the fix implemented:
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

interface Filter {
  company: boolean;
  gender: boolean;
}

export const App = () => {
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState<Filter>({
    company: false,
    gender: false,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(filter);
  }, []);

  const toggleMenu = (filterKey: keyof Filter) => {
    setFilter({ ...filter, [filterKey]: !filter[filterKey] });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        type="button"
        className="flex flex-row justify-center w-full"
        onClick={() => {
          toggleMenu("company");
        }}
      >
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};


